# ORA-00909 error when Insert object in object table

Tags: oracle, insert, oracle11gr2

I am getting an error ORA-00909 in when inserting an object of a superType in an object table. These are the definitions for the objects:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE address AS OBJECT (
    street VARCHAR(20),
    country VARCHAR(20),
    province VARCHAR(20),
    city VARCHAR2(20),
    zipcode VARCHAR(10)
) FINAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE company AS OBJECT (
    CIF VARCHAR2(9),
    code VARCHAR2(10),
    name VARCHAR2(20),
    signUpDate DATE,
    email VARCHAR2(20),
    adminAddress address
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE inCourseCompany UNDER company (
    postalAddress address,
    numEmployees NUMBER
) FINAL;
```

And the object table:

```
CREATE TABLE companies_objtab OF company (PRIMARY KEY CIF) OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS PRIMARY KEY;
```

I try to insert an object with the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO companies_objtab VALUES (
  company('J12345678','000001','Test Company',TO_DATE(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'',address('','','','',''))
  );
```

and I get error Error

> SQL: ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
>   00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments"

However, when I insert an object of the subtype inCourseCompany it is inserted correctly:

```
INSERT INTO companies_objtab VALUES (
  inCourseCompany('G11111111','','',TO_DATE(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'',address('','','','',''), address('','','','',''), 100)
  );
```

Any hint about what causes the error?

I am using Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.2.15.21 and Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried all your statements right as you posted them (copy-paste). Both on 12c and 11gR2. Everything worked, both inserts. The only thing I noticed is that your create table is a bit incorrect. This is the correct one (but this does not explain the error you get). HTH KR

```
CREATE TABLE companies_objtab OF company (CIF PRIMARY KEY) OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS PRIMARY KEY;
```

Maybe try dropping the table and creating it again.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I solved the problem. Silly one. In my original script I was using "lead" instead of "company" as the name of the type, but I changed it when I posted this issue. Turns out that LEAD is the name of an SQL function and the SQL interpreter interpreted that I was calling that function instead of my constructor. My bad, I didn't pay attention to the blue bold letters telling me that lead was "something else".